Prove that $\kappa_t(s,t) = - ( F_s(\kappa(s,t)) g^{-1}(s,t))_s g^{-1}(s,t) - \kappa^2(s,t) F(\kappa(s,t)).$

$\kappa(s, t)$ as the curvature at $\vec{x}(s, t).$ Then evolution
equation for the curvature $\kappa$, namely $\kappa_t(s,t) = - 
( F_s(\kappa(s,t)) g^{-1}(s,t))_s g^{-1}(s,t) - \kappa^2(s,t) F(\kappa(s,t)).$

My attempt:-
Reference:-https://math.berkeley.edu/~sethian/Papers/sethian.comm_math.85.pdf
Consider a simple, smooth, closed initial curve $\gamma(0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, let $\gamma(t)$ be the one-parameter family of curves, where $t \in [0, \infty)$ is time, generated by moving the initial curve along its normal vector field with speed $F$, a given function of the curvature. Let $\vec{x}(s, t)$ be the position vector which, at time $t$, parameterizes $\gamma(t)$ by $s$, $0 \leq s \leq S$, $\vec{x}(0, t) = \vec{x}(S, t)$. We assume the curve is parameterized so that the interior is on the left as we travel along the curve in the direction of increasing $s$.
With $\kappa(s, t)$ as the curvature at $\vec{x}(s, t)$, the equations of motion are:
$$\vec{n}(s, t) \cdot \frac{\partial \vec{x}(s, t)}{\partial t} = F(\kappa(s, t))$$
$$\vec{x}(s, 0) = \gamma(0), \quad s \in [0, S], \quad t \in [0, \infty)$$
where $\vec{n}(s, t)$ is the unit normal vector at $\vec{x}(s, t)$.
Written in terms of the coordinates $\vec{x}(s, t) = (x(s, t), y(s, t))$, an equivalent formulation is:
$$x_t = F\left(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}\right) y_s$$
$$y_t = -F\left(\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}\right) x_s$$
with:
$$(x(s, 0), y(s, 0)) = \gamma(0), \quad 0 \leq s \leq S.$$
Here, the curvature $\kappa(s,t)$ is expressed in terms of partials of $x$ and $y$ as $\frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}$. One can easily check that
$(x_t, y_t) \cdot (x_s, y_s) = 0 \quad \text{(motion along normals)}$
and that
$(x_t^2 + y_t^2)^{1/2} = F(\kappa) \quad \text{(speed function)}$.
In the above equations of motion, $s$ cannot be arclength.
The curvature $\kappa(s,t)$ is given by:
$
\kappa(s,t) = \frac{y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2}}.
$
To differentiate $\kappa(s,t)$ with respect to $t$, we use the quotient rule: Then we get expression like this
$
\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial t} = \frac{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{3/2} (y_{sst}x_s + y_{ss}x_{st} - x_{sst}y_s - x_{ss}y_{st}) 
- (y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s) \cdot 3 (x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{1/2} (x_sx_{st} + y_sy_{st})}{(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^3}.
$
We have $g=(x_s^2 + y_s^2)^{1/2}.$ Then
$
\frac{\partial \kappa}{\partial t} = \frac{g^3 (y_{sst}x_s + y_{ss}x_{st} - x_{sst}y_s - x_{ss}y_{st}) 
- (y_{ss}x_s - x_{ss}y_s) \cdot 3 g (x_sx_{st} + y_sy_{st})}{g^6}.$ I don't know how to proceed further.
